# Given that $T: V \rightarrow V$ be linear. why does it hold for $\dim(R(T^2))+\dim(N(T^2))=\dim(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The dimension theorem tells us $\dim(R(T))+\dim(N(T))=\dim(V)$, why does it hold for $\dim(R(T^2))+\dim(N(T^2))=\dim(V)$? Given that $T: V \rightarrow V$ be linear. What's the justification and how to prove that it is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably here $T$ is a linear transformation from vector space $V$ to $V$.
Then so is $T^2$.